# How to define faster scrolling than triple-wheel-down in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, scroll, elisp

One tantalizing shortcoming of Emacs is its weirdly broken scrolling mechanism on 'inertia-scrolling' OSX. After a lot of digging, the real problem seems to be that Emacs only registers keys for mouse wheel scrolling in one, two or three increments, that is `wheel-up|down`, `double-wheel-up|down` and `triple-wheel-up|down`.

However, the Mac trackpad seems to generate far bigger scrolling increments when scrolling fast. So, is there a way to generate more accurate scrolling messages that actually reflect the amount the trackpad was scrolled?

I am running Emacs 24.0.92 from http://emacsformacosx.com/.

Relevant `.emacs` settings:

```
(setq redisplay-dont-pause t)
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
```

Ultimately, what I would like to have is something like this:

```
(defun up-single () (interactive) (scroll-up 1))
(defun up-double () (interactive) (scroll-up 2))
(defun up-triple () (interactive) (scroll-up 3))
...

(global-set-key [wheel-down] 'up-single)
(global-set-key [double-wheel-down] 'up-double)
(global-set-key [triple-wheel-down] 'up-triple)
...
```

Comment: This is just me but if you're using Emacs, why are you even bothering to use the trackpad :). I actually see the opposite effect in MacPorts Emacs build, if I try to inertia scroll it scrolls all the way to the bottom and spams the message that it's the end of the buffer a lot. Are you using Aquamacs, precompiled binary,...?

Comment: You know, everyone works differently. While editing, I tend to not ever touch the mouse/trackpad. While reading though, I find the trackpad a more convenient way of scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if Emacs does not handle scroll events like OSX does. The `double-` and `triple-` modifiers and the `event-click-count` function [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283394/stefan) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035097/1034) do not signify single events of fast scrolling but merely that several scroll events happend in close succession. So when you begin to scroll, you get a 'click count' of 1, then 2, then 3 and so on.

On OSX, the trackpad does not issue individual scroll events like a mouse-wheel does. Instead, each event contains a pixel increment of how far the cursor moved since the last event. Programs should move their scroll-views by a distance proportional to that increment. However, to my knowledge Emacs scroll events do not contain that increment. Therefore, Emacs in its current form can not implement inertial scrolling.

PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand clearly what you want, but while Emacs only has distinct event names for single/double/triple clicks, it actually distinguishes up to sequences of 9 clicks.  The `event-click-count` can be used to extract this info from an event.

Comment: See my answer for why I did not accept your answer even though it is absolutely correct.